# Can't run WPF app

Tags: .net, wpf

I have Visual Basic Express 2008 and .net framework 3.5 on xp sp2.

I create a new wpf application, when I try run the application I get the following error.

" 'Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program 'C:\Documents and Settings\Mike\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WPF\bin\Debug\HelloWorld.exe'  Access Denied"

Any ideas?

**This problem only occurs with WPF application, winforms app runs just fine.

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this?  I just ran into the same problem and for-the-life-of-me can't get my project to run from VS 2008, XP SP3.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some program has an exclusive lock on your executable. Try a tool like Unlocker or WhoLockMe (there are many others) to find out, which process locks the file. Kill the process and your application should start.

Best Regards

Comment: Maybe try one of the most well-proven error resolving strategies: reboot ^^

Comment: I'm also getting this error-- have tried rebooting, resetting permissions on the project folder and starting in release mode.  Some other WPF projects will run (F5) correctly from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Visual Studio as an administrator on you pc? VS does not like it so much when it is not running as admin.

I dont know if this is still true with the express editions, but do you have to actually save the project before you can run the code? I have not used an express edition in a while but I remember something funky with how new project where created.

Comment: Yip. My user account is set as Computer Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try loading the program from inside Visual Studio using F11 or Control-F11, or did you use Windows Explorer instead? Make sure you are doing it from inside Visual Studio maybe.

Comment: I'm trying to run it from within the IDE. F5

Comment: Same here: F5 and Ctrl+F5 do not work, but double-clicking the generated executable in Exporer does.